# Prove that if $\chi(G) > k \wedge |\{\operatorname{ad}(H): \text{$H$ is an induced subgraph of $G$}\}|$ then $G$ has a $k-regular$ induced subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have found an interesting exercise in my introduction to graphs workbook:

Let $\operatorname{ad}(G) = \frac{2\vert E(G)\vert}{\vert V(G) \vert}$ and $\operatorname{mad}(G) = \max\{\operatorname{ad}(H): \text{$H$ is an induced subgraph of $G$}\}$.

Given a graph $G$ and a number $k \geq 3$, prove that if $\chi(G) > k \wedge \operatorname{mad}(G) \leq k \Rightarrow \exists A \subseteq V(G)$ such that $[A]_{G}$ is *k - regular*.

I believe this can proved by contradiction:

Given a $G$ and $k$ for which the properties hold, we assume that $G$ has no induced subgraph $H$ that is *k - regular*. We then prove that if $\nexists H$ then at least one of the property is false and thus we contradict ourselves however I can't quite figure out the connection between $H$ and the mentioned properties.

How would you go about solving this?